# How to reload/ refresh 'id' after specific time using Ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to reload/refresh the table id from where I can fetch update database.But problem is instead of refresh only table the whole page get reloaded. But I have catch the 'id' here. If any one fine what's the problem with the ajax one. Hope will help me to find it..

I'm using laravel here :

here is my view part:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered dataTable" id="example">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Serial No</td>
        <td>Title</td>
        <td>Description</td>                    
        <td>Action</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php $i=1; ?>
    @foreach($items as $row)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$i}}</td>
        <td class="title" data-id1="{{$row->id}}" contenteditable>{{$row->title}}</td>  
        <td class="description" data-id2="{{$row->id}}" contenteditable>{{$row->description}}</td>  
        <td>    
            <button type="button" onclick="deleteItem({{ $row->id }})" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php $i++; ?>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
</table>
```

here is javaScript with Ajax part:

```
<script>
function autoRefresh_div()
{
    $("#example").load(ajax());// a function which will load data from other file after x seconds
}
function ajax(){
    $.ajax({  
        url:"{{url('listA')}}",  
        method:"get",                                                       
        success: function(result) {
           location.reload();
        } 
    }); 
}
setInterval('autoRefresh_div()', 2000); // refresh div after 5 secs
</script>
```

And here is the route part:

```
Route::get('listA',function(Request $request){
    $items=\App\Item::all();
    return Response::json($items);  
});
```

Comment: Is your ID "example" in your actual code?  Does it go wrong if you change your ID to "example" in your code?

Comment: I used `<table class="table table-striped table-bordered dataTable" id="example">`

Comment: Entire page is getting refreshed because of `location.reload();`

Comment: The reason I ask, is because sometimes people use characters that have meaning in their ID, eg "an.example" then try to reference it as `$("#an.example")` which doesn't work as "." means class.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go, It depends on you if you want this after success or before.

```
setInterval(function()
{
  $('#YOUR DIV').load(document.URL +  ' #YOUR DIV');
}, 30000);
```

Comment: Are you sure about this ?

`load(document.URL +  ' #YOUR DIV');`

Comment: Yes, am sure. Kindly try it yourself. It reloads that div.

Comment: see here the problem of your solution is you have represent it wrong ..
it should be like :  `$("#example").load("list #example");`
means you should avoid the `'+'` sign

Comment: I don't know about your div and + sign is for concatenation between div and function. Please up vote and accept the answer if it solves your purpose. Thanks!

Comment: ohh ..One Question.. after calling that javascript it's automatically create a row in table..How to avoid..can you explain? is that connected with the above code?

Comment: Can you explain more about it or update your new code so it is very clear for me to analyze.

Comment: See, I have used you code. But the problem I'm facing is the div will reload after 3 seconds but after reloading, it automatically create a empty row which shouldn't happen ..means with the existing table it creates a empty row in table ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122336/discussion-between-syed-noman-and-user57).

Answer (score 0):

Entire page is getting refreshed because of `location.reload();`. Try below code.

```js
function autoRefresh_div() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "{{url('listA')}}",
    method: "get",
    success: function(result) {
      $("#example").html(result);
    }
  });
}

setInterval(autoRefresh_div(), 5000); // refresh div after 5 secs
```

Comment: I have used you code, But while it refresh the whole table gone

Comment: Looks like you're returning JSON, in which case you'll have to rebuild the table.  Might be easier to return some partial html.